# Displacement node not working with complex mesh

Tags: cycles-render-engine, node-editor, displacement

I'm trying to make displacement to a mountain. I could put displacement modifier that would work just fine but I want displacement just some parts of the mountain and I can't get it right with that modifier. With nodes I get it right spots but displacement node won't work with my mesh. I've tried displacement with simple objects like plane and it work fine but when I make some geometry displacement node goes crazy. Even if I make more subdivisions (my 8Gb of ram ends in eight million verts) it won't be any better. I've spent several tens of hours with this problem and nothing seems to work with me.

Here is some pics of my problem:

[image]

[image]

.blend file:
[image]

Sorry for my bad English and thank you for your replies in advance!

Comment: Hi, you can provide the blend file in here https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ , just follow the instructions and you're done.

Comment: Ironic considering your file has perfect example of how it works. 
Anyhow to fix this particular case change the mid level from 0.5 to 0 and then you can start increasing 'height' by .1 step by step to see the mesh get displaced along it's normals.
When using B&W texture midpoint determines which value of grey represents the current surface... I don't know why when no texture map plugged in the midpoint seems to reverse the direction of displacement but that is what it seems to do.